# how to find database sessionids for each runstream method api call while executing query in gcloud spanner?

Tags: node.js, graphql, google-cloud-spanner

we are seeing database sessions more than the max connections configured.

database.runStream( queryOptions)

below was the session configuration :
const SESSIONCONFIG = {
    max: 10,
    min: 1,
    keepAlive: 10
};

How can we print sessionid using database.runStream api call to ensure same sessionid was reused?

created database connection, using session config options. session pool displayed with below details:

```
'
pool_:
   SessionPool {
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] { error: [Function: bound emit], close: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 2,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     isOpen: true,
     database: [Circular],
     options:
      { acquireTimeout: Infinity,
        concurrency: Infinity,
        fail: false,
        idlesAfter: 10,
        keepAlive: '1',
        labels: [Object],
        max: '5',
        maxIdle: 1,
        min: '1',
        writes: 0 },
     _myDatabaseConnection: { readonly: [Array], readwrite: [], borrowed: Set {} },
     _requests:
      PQueue {
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _carryoverConcurrencyCount: false,
        _isIntervalIgnored: true,
        _intervalCount: 1,
        _intervalCap: Infinity,
        _interval: 0,
        _intervalId: null,
        _intervalEnd: 0,
        _timeoutId: null,
        queue: [PriorityQueue],
        _queueClass: [Function: PriorityQueue],
        _pendingCount: 0,
        _concurrency: Infinity,
        _isPaused: false,
        _resolveEmpty: [Function],
        _resolveIdle: [Function] },
     _acquires:
      PQueue {
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _carryoverConcurrencyCount: false,
        _isIntervalIgnored: true,
        _intervalCount: 1,
        _intervalCap: Infinity,
        _interval: 0,
        _intervalId: null,
        _intervalEnd: 0,
        _timeoutId: null,
        queue: [PriorityQueue],
        _queueClass: [Function: PriorityQueue],
        _pendingCount: 0,
        _concurrency: 1,
        _isPaused: false,
        _resolveEmpty: [Function],
        _resolveIdle: [Function] },
     _traces: Map {},
     _onClose: Promise { <pending> },
     _evictHandle:
      Timeout {
        _called: false,
        _idleTimeout: 600000,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idleStart: 1644,
        _onTimeout: [Function],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: 600000,
        _destroyed: false,
        _handle: [Timer],
        [Symbol(unrefed)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 76,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 1 },
     _pingHandle:
      Timeout {
        _called: false,
        _idleTimeout: 60000,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idleStart: 1644,
        _onTimeout: [Function],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: 60000,
        _destroyed: false,
        _handle: [Timer],
        [Symbol(unrefed)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 78,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 1 } } }'


return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    database.runStream(queryOptions)
        .on('error', (error) => {
       // how to ensure same session id object being used

            logger.error( error);
            reject(error);
        })
        .on('data', (row) => {
                        allData.push(row.toJSON());
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            if (allData.length === 1) {

                resolve(allData[0]);
            } 
        });
});
```

Expected: return session to pool once query execution complete without closing.

Current: Every time a new session created and total number of sessions created exceeds maximum allocated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not yet sure whether it's possible to get the session ID used by the `runStream` query. But something you can try is to call [`Database.getSessions`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/spanner/latest/Database.html#getSessions) and print the IDs of all sessions. Then you can check at each call to `runStream` whether new sessions are added or if the total number of sessions exceeds the maximum that you've configured.

How are you checking that it's creating more than the configured max number of sessions?

Looking at the `runStream` [implementation](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-spanner/blob/0ea0161ddd278a887e38c76d779d9c788e243dff/src/database.ts#L1604), for each query execution, it is taking a read session from the configured session pool. The pool will [not create any more sessions](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-spanner/blob/f8ad0ece28e99dd9c6d7e985de56bd1b376f4712/src/session-pool.ts#L746) after it's full.